# Call a method from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to call a method from another form. My try:

```
public partial class newLedPopUp : Form
{
    Form1 back = new Form1();
    back.output();
    Close();
}
```

and

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    newLedPopUp popup = new newLedPopUp();

    public void output()
    {
        button3_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me? I really can't find my error and I've been looking for a very long time.

Comment: So what is the error message?

Comment: No error message, but output is not executed in debugger

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Instead of creating an instance of a new Form, you probably need an instance of already opened form and call the method from there. You can try:

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["yourForm"] != null)
    {
        (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["yourForm"] as Form1).Output();
    }
```

plus you can replace calling the `button3_Click(null,null)` in your `Output` method, by placing the code of the event in a separate method and then calling that method against your button click event or your public output method

Comment: It works.. i have never heard from the class Application.Openforms... Thanks for that :)

Comment: @Pengu, you are welcome, [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) is a property of Application class

Comment: +1 I have also never heard of Application.OpernForms[""], must have learned in your new project ;).

Comment: This works well but is the the standard/only way of accessing an open instance of Form?

Comment: Inside "if statement" what does "your Form" should be replaced with?

Comment: @YashSaraiya, from doc `This collection can be searched by index position or by the Name of the Form.` , you can pass `"Form1"` for the default `Form1`. Just double check the `Name` property and use that as the indexer.

Answer (score 2):

You are closing `Form1` immediately after calling `output` method. Thus I assume, you have some business-related, or data access logic there. Try to move code, which is executed on `button3_Click` event handler, to separate object

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Output()
    {
       // move here button3_Click code
    }
}
```

Then create Foo and pass it to both forms (or you can instantiate it inside forms without dependency injection)

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Form1 form1 = new Form1(foo);
LedPopUp form2 = new LedPopUp(foo);
```

And use it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     private Foo _foo;
     // without dependency injection: private Foo _foo = new Foo();         

     public Form1(Foo foo)
     {
         _foo = foo;
     }

     protected void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         _foo.Output();
     }
}
```