# Use function from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

**UPDATED**

MDIparent Form:

```
public void sample()
{
textBox1.Text = "Sample";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MDIParent1 p = new MDIParent1();
LogInForm LogIn = new LogInForm(p); 
DialogResult res = LogIn.ShowDialog()
}
```

LogInForm:

```
private MDIParent1 _p;
public LogInForm(MDIParent1 p)
{
InitializeComponent();
_p = p;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
_p.sample();
this.Close();
}
```

_p.sample(); does not work

Comment: What is the new problem after updating?

Comment: the function sample() does not fires

Comment: Try debugging (set breakpoint at the code line calling `sample()` and see if it jumps at there. I guess you haven't registered the `button1_Click` with the `Click` event of the `button1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void sample()
{
   textBox1.Text = "Sample";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MDIParent1 p = new MDIParent1();
   LogInForm LogIn = new LogInForm(p); 
   DialogResult res = LogIn.ShowDialog()
}
```

On button click here, you are creating a *NEW* `MDIParent1` and passing that to the new  `LogInFOrm`

```
private MDIParent1 _p;
public LogInForm(MDIParent1 p)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   _p = p;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _p.sample();
}
```

Here you call the `sample` method on the form you passed in (which has been instanitated on the previous form, but never actually rendered).To render it you need to call `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`

If you were meaning to pass in the form where the button was clicked you could have done this

```
LogInForm LogIn = new LogInForm(this);
```

or you could have used `Application.OpenForms` and not passed the form at all.

Comment: Thank you James :) . Is Application.OpenForms is [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12890788/2493889)

Comment: Yeah that is pretty much all there is to it. All you are doing is getting an open form by name if it exists and casting it to the correct form type. You can then access its method and properties.

Comment: Application.OpenForms method is mure convenient. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
p = _p;
```

to

```
_p = p;
```

That is all...

Comment: @SquarePonge `Doesn't work` doesn't mean anything to me. What error do you get? Is it possible that you see nothing because you create a new instance of `MDIParent1` instead of passing the current one?

Comment: @SquarePonge he suggested you to change `p = _p` to `_p = p` in the `LogInForm(MDIParent1 p)` constructor, have you done following so?

Comment: @SquarePonge I think it *does* fire, reread my previous comment....(Easy to test: put a break-point and debug your code.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

```
p = _p;
```

on:

```
_p = p;
```

This might work

Comment: That is weird, try debugging