# Updating Combobox after database operations returns `System.NullReferenceException`

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, nullreferenceexception

In order to update the listing of items in a `ComboBox` code-named `PartId` I created a method `PopulatePartyIdCombobox()` and I call it after updating/deleting/saving new items to database, to reflect those changes in `PartId` and it works all fine on same `Form1`.

In order to use the `PopulatePartyIdCombobox()` on another form named `Add_Party`,i used `Application.OpenForms` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890754/call-a-method-from-another-form) .

Following is the way i use:

```
    if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Add_Party"] != null)
        {

            (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Add_Party"] as Form1).PopulatePartyIdCombobox();


        }
```

From `Form1.cs`

```
   public void PopulatePartyIdCombobox()
    {

        string str = "select CP_id from  tbl_partyinfo";
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = str;

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            PartId.Items.Add(reader[0]);

        }
        reader.Close();



    }
```

but it on debug says:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred 
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Isn't this error un-related or why so?

Is there any alternative method where i can get the combobox updated after database updation.

Comment: Which line is highlighting when you get the error?

Comment: @Sayka  It's `(System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Add_Party"] as Form1).PopulatePartyIdCombobox()` returning error

Comment: What is the other form's name? 'Add_Party'?

Answer (score 1):

make a 'new' instance from Form1 or just put the method in a public static class to avoid all those code to get methods into a form from another form

1. Make a new instance of the form containing the method to use
2. Make the method with a parameter of type ComboBox (to send the name of the combo box you need to update or populate with data)

Or

1. Create a public class
2. Declare a method in this class, and the method is:

```cs
internal static void FillComboBox(ComboBox comboBoxName, string valueMember, string displayMember, string tableName)
    {
        SqlConnection connName = new SqlConnection();
        connName.ConnectionString = "YourSqlConnString";
        connName.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select " + valueMember + " ," + displayMember + "  from " + tableName, connName);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        comboBoxName.ValueMember = valueMember;
        comboBoxName.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        comboBoxName.DataSource = dt;
        connName.Close();
    }
```

You can handle the method with try,catch and also you can change the sql select statement like you want

Comment: I meant :
Create a public class that has a static method with some parameters so you can call it from wherever you want

Comment: This is right: _make a 'new' instance from Form1_
but 
Creating public class,embedding a method there to conatin `PartId.Items.Add(reader[0])` wouldn't give error ? for  `PartId` is a part of form (combobox)

Comment: Upvoted for partial workable solution but if u provide an insight to a class would be helpful more

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem

Check how you have done casting

```
(Application.OpenForms["Add_Party"] as Form1).PopulatePartyIdCombobox();
```

As Form1? How can you cast the Form Add_Party to Form1?

The statement Application.OpenForms["Add_Party"] looks for an opened form named Add_Party and returns if exists. So do like..

```
Form1 _form1 = (Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1);
_form1.PopulatePartyIdCombobox();
```

Comment: So,how should i access `PopulatePartyCombobox` now from `Add_Party` ?
How would  casting  help me  **change code based on your requirement** ?

Comment: Is there a function named **PopulatePartyCombobox()** in your Add_Party Form?

Comment: No ,that i want to import/use from Form1

Comment: (Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1).PopulatePartyIdCombobox();

Comment: Please edit and correct your ans.to make it acceptable

Comment: Upvoted for such nice efforts on your side but didn't work for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73192/discussion-between-sayka-and-crystal-heart).

Answer (score 0):

But what i did simple *alternative method where i can get the combobox updated after database updation*.

Create an exit button on same form i.e.`Add_Party` and instantiating `Form1`.This will make sure the `PartId`(combobox on `Form1`) contains latest data by loading `Form1` here from exit event.

```
   private void btnexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.PopulatePartyIdCombobox();
        f1.Show();

        this.Close();
      }
```