# Delete selected rows from DataGridView after password is correct

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I want to delete selected rows from a datagridview that is connected to an Access Database after the user enters correct password in another form.

I created a method that should be called from form 2 after password is correct, but nothing happens.

Form1:

```
public void DeleteSelectedRows()
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                string ID = item.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                conn_SN.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = conn_SN;
                command.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM SN WHERE ID=" + ID;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn_SN.Close();
            }
        }
```

This is how I call the method from form 2:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textbox.Text=="admin")
    {
        Form1 form = Form1();
        form.DeleteSelectedRows();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of `ID` column? Did you debug your code and see what happens?

Comment: this code works perfectly if is called from form1 (where the datagridview is). But when I try to call it from another form it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Any kind of error?

Comment: Nope. Nothing happens.

Comment: How do you call the function from the second Form? Maybe this could help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890754/call-a-method-from-another-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to call the method like this:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textbox.Text=="admin")
    {
    var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Meniu>().Single();
    form.DeleteSelectedRows();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Owner property. I am just giving an example code. Check this and modify for your's.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(dataGridView1);
        From2.Text = "some title text";
form2.Owner=this;
        form2.ShowDialog(this);

//And on form2 ; 
((Form1)this.Owner).YOURMETHODTODELETE(your parameter)
```

implement YOURMETHODTODELETE to delete row from grid then refresh your grid1

Comment: Did you try my solution?. Please tell us how did you solve the problem so that it will be learning experience for some body in the world. If the answer provided my stack overflow members is useful to you please accept and upvote the answer. You can also down vote the answer if the answer is not useful or dangerously incorrect.