# call event with parameters from another event , both different namespace

Tags: c#

I would like to call an event having parameters from another event, both have different namespaces, is it passable to do this?

```
public void event1(object1 sender, eventArgs e1)
{
// code goes here
}

public void event2(object2 sender, eventArgs e2)
{
// here I want call event1 with parametersenter code here
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: Events can't be called, they can be raised, and your question does not contain nearly enough details to answer. Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: That's not event, but event-handler and it sounds like you just want to run piece of code from another window/form. There are dozens of question like this around (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12890754/1997232)). You already have made event-handler public (though better is to create a dedicated public method which is called by event handler and from another class), now you just need instance of corresponding object (containing event handler you want to run), it has to be either passed or obtained via some *manager* class (such as `Application.OpenForms` in winforms).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is not in terms of events being called but just methods being called.

If in the simplest terms your events just called `Method1` and `Method2` respectively then you could easily have `Method1` call `Method2` and do whatever it does.

You could raise potentially raise `event1` from inside `event2` but it doesn't necessarily make sense to do so (for example if it is a click event it should only be raised by a click. It is best to just refactor common code into a method that can be easily called using standard OOP techniques. In my code below I've made the extracted methods static methods so they are easier to call from other objects and assumed that `Method1` is in `Class1` (not explicitly shown) which is in `Namespace1`. You may need to do things slightly differently if you need them to be non-static methods.

Here's the example of what I mean.

```
public void event1(object1 sender, eventArgs e1)
{
    var myParameter = ...;
    Method1(myParameter);
}

public static void Method1(object myParameter)
{
    // code goes here
}

public void event2(object2 sender, eventArgs e2)
{
    var myParameter = ...;
    Method2(myParameter);
}

public static void Method2(object myParameter)
{
    Namespace1.Class1.Method1(myParameter);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using "MyNameSpace";
thats all you need.
I need to write 30 characters so

## include "mynamespace" for c++.

Unless i misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Erm, its tagged C# not C++. PS - I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Oh well. I know but i couldn't leave a message under 30 characters. Man I've only used this forum a couple times but the post restrictions really suck. Also the bolding automatically happened after I posted.