# c#-How to stop an audio file from a different form(not the one it is playing in)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, audio

I am a beginner in c# and I am coding a little game in winform (Visual Studio 2015) but I have trouble with the audio;basically the menu form runs an audio file,the music, using this script:

```
WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            player.URL = "Main Theme.mp3";
            player.controls.play();
        }
```

And when you press the play button and start another form(let's call it Intro.cs for example) from the menu,the script

```
 player.controls.stop();
```

stop the music.Now,the problem is that I don't know how to stop the music from another form(the "Load" form) that open Intro.cs too,because

```
player.controls.stop();
```

doesn't work anymore and I can't find the solution to this anywhere.Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a method from another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890754/call-a-method-from-another-form)

Comment: either make a function on form1, as public so you can call it, which stops it, or, make the player public so you can control it from other places.. etc you havent seemingly showed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could achieve that. I think the easiest way would be to make the WindowsMediaPlayer object as a static and then access it from the other Form.

in Form1 it could look like this:

```
public static WindowsMediaPlayer player;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
        player.URL = "Main Theme.mp3";
        player.controls.play();
    }
```

and then from the other Form

```
Form1.player.controls.stop();
```