# I want to call a method from a different form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my TextBox to take information and run the code from a business object from a different form. I want it to run whenever the button is clicked.

I am having problems initializing the code. In theStudent.cs form it works fine I just want to pull the SelectDB() method into the StudentForm.

```
namespace SchoolReg{

public partial class StudentForm : Form
{

    public StudentForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void StudentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ignore
    }



    private void StudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Student s1;
        s1 = new Student();
        txtboxIDStu.Text = s1.SelectDB(int);

    }

    private void txtboxIDStu_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ignore
    }
}


 namespace SchoolReg{


class Student : person
{


    private double gpa;




    //constructors 
    public Student():base()
    {

        gpa = 0;

    }

    public Student(int id, string fn, string ln,  Address a1, string em, double gp) : base(id,fn,ln,a1,em)
    {

        gpa = gp;

    }

    //behaviors
    public void setgpa(double gp) { gpa = gp; }
    public double getgpa() { return gpa; }




    //display 
    public void Display()
    {
        base.display();
        Console.WriteLine("===================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Gpa = " + gpa);
        Console.WriteLine("===================================");

    }


    public System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter OleDbDataAdapter2;
    public System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand OleDbSelectCommand2;
    public System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand OleDbInsertCommand2;
    public System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand OleDbUpdateCommand2;
    public System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand OleDbDeleteCommand2;
    public System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection OleDbConnection2;
    public string cmd;

    public Student(int id)
    {
        SelectDB(id);
    }

    public void DBSetup()
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbSelectCommand2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        OleDbInsertCommand2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        OleDbUpdateCommand2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDeleteCommand2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        OleDbConnection2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();


        OleDbDataAdapter2.DeleteCommand = OleDbDeleteCommand2;
        OleDbDataAdapter2.InsertCommand = OleDbInsertCommand2;
        OleDbDataAdapter2.SelectCommand = OleDbSelectCommand2;
        OleDbDataAdapter2.UpdateCommand = OleDbUpdateCommand2;

        OleDbConnection2.ConnectionString = "Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=;Jet OLEDB:Database L" +
        "ocking Mode=1;Data Source=C:\\Users\\nicho\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Database c#\\RegistrationMDB.mdb;J" +
        "et OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:System datab" +
        "ase=;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;persist security info=False;Extended Properties=;Mode=S" +
        "hare Deny None;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet " +
        "OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repai" +
        "r=False;User ID=Admin;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1";   



    }

    public void SelectDB(int id)
    {
        DBSetup();
        cmd = "Select * from Students where ID =" + id;
        OleDbDataAdapter2.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmd;
        OleDbDataAdapter2.SelectCommand.Connection = OleDbConnection2;
        Console.WriteLine(cmd);

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection2.Open();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader dr;
            dr = OleDbDataAdapter2.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            dr.Read();

            Id = id;
            setfname(dr.GetValue(1) + "");
            setlname(dr.GetValue(2) + "");
            Address a1 = new Address(dr.GetValue(3) + "", dr.GetValue(4) + "", dr.GetValue(5) + "", long.Parse(dr.GetValue(6)+""));
            setAddr(a1);
            setemail(dr.GetValue(7) + "");
            setgpa(Double.Parse(dr.GetValue(8) + ""));

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            OleDbConnection2.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("===================================");
        getSchedule();
        Console.WriteLine("===================================");

    }
```

/*I think I am messing up in the StudentForm form. I'm sorry in advance because I feel like the answer is simple. Also for the messy layout, I don't usually post.*/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a method from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890754/call-a-method-from-another-form)

Comment: Or any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+C%23+winforms+call+method+in+another+form)

Comment: @gunr2171 I don't think those will help. OP isn't trying to call a method from another form (despite the title), he's trying to call a method from his Student object.

Comment: There's an incredible amount of code here that's totally unrelated to the problem. I scrolled through quickly and couldn't even find the part that actually matters. While it's much better to post too much code than too little, still, it's a big help to us if you trim it down to the part that's critical to the problem you're asking about.

Comment: @NickLodde Can you describe what you're trying to achieve?


It looks like that method on `Student` looks up the `Student` in the database, pulls the data back, and populates the `Student` object. 

Are you trying to take an ID in `StudentForm`, create a new `Student` object based on that ID, and then use `SelectDB()` to populate the `Student` object from the row in the database that matches that `Student`'s ID?

Comment: Yes @JoeCullinan that exactly it, messed up how on wording the question.  Sorry for the too much code..?

Comment: Also, thanks @gunr2171 those might also have helped.

Comment: Posting too much code, and vague statements like “I am having problems” are symptoms of [no debugging](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). You have to do that first.

Comment: @NickLodde I see two obvious problems here: 1) You call `s1.SelectDB(int)`,  which is nonsensical: `Student.SelectDB(int id)` wants you to pass a student ID, which is an integer. You need to give it *an integer* there. Some specific integral number: `9`, `112`, something like that. Where and how are you choosing which student you want to look at? 2) You define `void SelectDB(int id)`, where you very clearly tell the compiler that the method returns *nothing*. That's what the `void` means: "This method returns nothing". Then you try to assign the return value to `txtboxIDStu.Text`.

Comment: Sorry? Thought it would help..? @DourHighArch

Comment: @NickLodde But you went to some trouble to guarantee that SelectDB() has no return value. What *do* you want to display in `txtboxIDStu.Text`? Some property of `s1`? The return value of some method of `s1`, like maybe `getgpa()`? 3) If you had *given any hint at all* about the specific problem you are having, that would have been helpful. You're not just asking us to fix your problem. You're asking is to *find out what your problem is*, because you didn't bother telling us about it. You could have told us. Didn't you think that was important?

Comment: Okay thanks, I see what you mean @ED Plunkett

Comment: @NickLodde A [quick read here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (well, quick-*ish*) will save you a lot of time and trouble going around and around with people after you post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you're pretty close here, but you're missing a few steps

```
    private void StudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    Student s1;
    s1 = new Student();
    txtboxIDStu.Text = s1.SelectDB(int);

    }
```

should be something like this

```
    private void StudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string studentIdString = this.TEXTBOXNAME.Text; // This fetches the string from the input box and stores it. Replace TEXTBOXNAME with the name of your textbox that holds the ID.
        bool inputIsNumber = Int32.TryParse(studentIdString , out studentIdInt); //Int32 TryParse tries to convert a given string into an integer. If it works inputIsNumber will be true, and the studentIdInt will be available as a variable. 
        if(inputIsNumber == false){
            txtboxIDStu.Text = "Please enter a valid number";
            return; //Bail out if we can't turn the string into a number
        }
        Student s1 = new Student(studentIdInt); //We're going to use the ID we created to build the student using the constructor

        txtboxIDStu.Text = s1.fname + " " + s1.lastname; // By the time we've gotten here the constructor has fired, which also fired SelectDB() on that student. This just prints the name of the student, but if you want to improve this look up "Overrides" and create a ToString() override on your Student class.

    }
```

You already have a constructor for student that takes an Id, which is exactly what we need.

```
    public Student(int id)
    {
       SelectDB(id); 
    }
```